# Webpage displays differently on different screens

Tags: html, css, mobile, display

I'm trying to get my website to be display the way that it was designed. I have an iMac but when I view it on a MacBook Pro and my phone, the divs on one of my pages lose their proportions and it's not looking the way it should. Here's the link to my page:http://www.wintonbrownmusic.online/Music%20Site%20Beat%20Making.html

Here's the CSS for my page:

```
header, section, footer, aside, nav, main, article, figure {
display: block; 
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

a {
display: inline-block;
width: 90px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none; 
font-family: Gagalin;
color: #404040;
font-size: 20px;
}

li {
width: 100px;
margin: auto;
display: inline;
}

p {
font-family: Arial;
padding-left: 10px;

}

a:hover, a:active {
padding-bottom:8px;
background: transparent;
border-bottom: 3px solid #FA8440; 
}

a:active {
color: #FA8440;
}

.newspaper {
-webkit-columns: 100px 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-columns: 100px 3; /* Firefox */
columns: 100px 3;
font-family: Arial;
}

h2 {
font-family: Gagalin;
padding-left: 10px;
}

footer {
background-color:black;
color:white;
clear:both;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
}

.blurb {
margin:5px 0 10px 10px;
width:425px;
height: 230px;
background:#1a1a1a;
border: 6px solid #4d4d4d;
padding: 30px;
float: right;
font-family: Arial;
color: White;
padding-right:50px;
}

.container-fluid {
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: 0 auto;
width: 65%;
}
```

I could use some assistance on what code I can use to make this page appear the same in all browsers, all pages and even phones.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* You have the CSS here but not the HTML.

Comment: Ever thought about using a framework like bootstrap to help handle multiple devices / responsive development?

Comment: This is called "responsive web design" and it just doesn't happen by itself. It is a very large topic and is usually achieved by the use of responsive frameworks (like Bootstrap) and the use of `@media` queries.

Comment: With bootstrap, how could I use their framework with my HTML? Would I have to re-do it in bootstrap?

Comment: @W.Brown Yes you would have to redo it. You will have to put you existing HTML in the Bootstrap grid system, which is responsive, and that will get you most of the way there, but not all the way. You will have to take some time to learn Bootstrap first so you know how to use it properly. This will take some time... like I said... this is a large topic. If you don't have the time then hire a web developer. People often under estimate how complex making a website can be.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its a resolution problem(or cross browser issue) since I see your fixing width and height in ur css.

There are 2 Solutions to ur problem:

1. make your containers/divs by percentage, even after doing that you may still face some issues.
2. What I would **recommend** is scrap existing html and redo it using a styling framework like bootstrap(http://getbootstrap.com/) this would allow you to make your website responsive and it wont break on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the design is not responsive (does not naturally adjust to different screen sizes and formats).  Responsive design is a huge topic that can't really be covered in the contents of once conversation box, so I am adding some links for you to look at.

Responsive web design basics:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/

Media queries:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks for your help.